# ViewPager showing last created fragment instead of current item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I created an activity with a ViewPager that should show items from a list of objects.
The starting position is passed trough the activity intent, and this works great.
In the OnCreateView of the fragment being created I load the values from the list and show them.
I know that the ViewPager automatically loads the previous and the next Item of the selected one.
The problem is that in the activity I see the last fragment created and not the current one.

This is the Activity code:

```
public class SwipeLupettoDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private int lupetto_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe_lupetto_detail);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    lupetto_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("ID_Lupetto", 0);
    int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("POSITION", 0);
    Log.d("RECIEVED", "POSITION from intent: " + position);
    Log.d("RECIEVED", "ID_Lupetto from intent: " + lupetto_id);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position-1);
    mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) { }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d("POSITION", "OnPageSelected CurrentItem: " + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Edit_Lupetto.class);
            intent.putExtra("ID_Lupetto", lupetto_id);
            Log.d("Activity Transition", "Transazione, Inviato ID_lupetto: " + lupetto_id);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final List<Lupetto> lupettoList = Lupetto.listAll(Lupetto.class, "SESTIGLIA, PISTA " + "DESC");
    private static final String POSITION = "position";
    private int lupetto_id;
    private Lupetto lupetto;
    private Anagrafica anagrafica;
    private View rootView;

    public PlaceholderFragment() { }

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(POSITION, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lupetto_detail, container, false);
        if (getArguments().containsKey(POSITION)) {
            Activity activity = this.getActivity();
            lupetto_id = getArguments().getInt(POSITION, 0);
            if (lupetto_id < 0) {
                lupetto_id = activity.getIntent().getIntExtra(POSITION, 0);
            }
            lupetto = lupettoList.get(lupetto_id);
            anagrafica = lupetto.Anagrafica;
            Log.d("PAGEVIEW", "OnCreateView Position: " + lupetto_id);
            Log.d("LOAD", "OnCreateView LoadingObject: " + lupetto.Nome + " " + lupetto.Cognome);
            CollapsingToolbarLayout appBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
            if (appBarLayout != null) {
                appBarLayout.setTitle(lupetto.Nome + " " + lupetto.Cognome);
            }
        }

        List<Specialità> specs;
        List<Prova> provs;
        if (lupetto != null) {
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_email)).setText(anagrafica.Email);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_indirizzo)).setText(anagrafica.Indirizzo);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_pista)).setText(lupetto.Pista.toString());
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_sestiglia)).setText(lupetto.Sestiglia.toString());
            ((CheckedTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ctb_cda)).setChecked(lupetto.CdA);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fisso)).setText(anagrafica.Tel_fisso);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_madre)).setText(anagrafica.Cell_Madre);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_padre)).setText(anagrafica.Cell_Padre);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_data)).setText(anagrafica.DataNascita);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_luogo)).setText(anagrafica.Luogo_Nascita);
            specs = Specialità.stringToIDs(lupetto.Specialità);
            provs = Prova.IDStringToProveList(lupetto.Prove);

            //POPOLAZIONE ListView Spec
            TextView tv_spec;
            ScrollView lv = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_Specialità);
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) lv.getChildAt(0);
            for (Specialità spec : specs) {
                tv_spec = new TextView(getContext());
                tv_spec.setText(spec.Nome);
                tv_spec.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
                linearLayout.addView(tv_spec);
            }
            TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
            getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackgroundBorderless,
                    typedValue, true);
            lv = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_Prove);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) lv.getChildAt(0);
            for (Prova p : provs) {
                final int index = Prova.allProve.indexOf(p);
                tv_spec = new TextView(getContext());
                tv_spec.setText(p.Nome);
                tv_spec.setSingleLine(true);
                tv_spec.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
                tv_spec.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                tv_spec.setTag(index);
                tv_spec.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
                tv_spec.setClickable(true);
                tv_spec.setBackgroundResource(typedValue.resourceId);
                tv_spec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onClick(View v) {
                                                   Intent i = new Intent(
                                                           getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                                           ProvaDettaglio.class);
                                                   i.putExtra("ID_Prova", (int) v.getTag());
                                                   i.putExtra("ID_Lupetto", lupetto_id);
                                                   startActivity(i);
                                               }
                                           }
                );
                linearLayout.addView(tv_spec);
            }
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (int) Lupetto.count(Lupetto.class);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Lupetto l = PlaceholderFragment.lupettoList.get(position);
        return  l.Nome + " " + l.Cognome;
    }
}
}
```

This instead is the log that I see from when the activity is created and after some swipe left and right:

```
10-28 10:17:28.425  D/RECIEVED: POSITION: 1
10-28 10:17:28.425  D/RECIEVED: ID_Lupetto: 2
10-28 10:17:28.521  D/PAGEVIEW: OnCreateView Position: 0
10-28 10:17:28.522  D/LOAD: OnCreateView LoadingObject: A  
10-28 10:17:28.526  D/PAGEVIEW: OnCreateView Position: 0
10-28 10:17:28.526  D/LOAD: OnCreateView LoadingObject: A  
10-28 10:17:31.324  D/POSITION: OnPageSelected CurrentItem: 1
10-28 10:17:31.867  D/PAGEVIEW: OnCreateView Position: 1
10-28 10:17:31.867  D/LOAD: OnCreateView LoadingObject: B   
10-28 10:17:32.027  D/POSITION: OnPageSelected CurrentItem: 2
10-28 10:17:32.299  D/PAGEVIEW: OnCreateView Position: 2
10-28 10:17:32.299  D/LOAD: OnCreateView LoadingObject: C  
10-28 10:17:32.621  D/POSITION: OnPageSelected CurrentItem: 3
10-28 10:17:33.868  D/POSITION: OnPageSelected CurrentItem: 2
10-28 10:17:34.126  D/PAGEVIEW: OnCreateView Position: 0
10-28 10:17:34.126  D/LOAD: OnCreateView LoadingObject: A  
10-28 10:17:34.453  D/POSITION: OnPageSelected CurrentItem: 1
10-28 10:17:34.738  D/PAGEVIEW: OnCreateView Position: 0
10-28 10:17:34.738  D/LOAD: OnCreateView LoadingObject: A  
10-28 10:17:35.018  D/POSITION: OnPageSelected CurrentItem: 0
10-28 10:17:36.136  D/POSITION: OnPageSelected CurrentItem: 1
10-28 10:17:36.353  D/PAGEVIEW: OnCreateView Position: 1
10-28 10:17:36.353  D/LOAD: OnCreateView LoadingObject: B   
10-28 10:17:36.651  D/POSITION: OnPageSelected CurrentItem: 2
10-28 10:17:36.823  D/PAGEVIEW: OnCreateView Position: 2
10-28 10:17:36.823  D/LOAD: OnCreateView LoadingObject: C  
10-28 10:17:37.163  D/POSITION: OnPageSelected CurrentItem: 3
10-28 10:17:38.901  D/POSITION: OnPageSelected CurrentItem: 2
10-28 10:17:39.169  D/PAGEVIEW: OnCreateView Position: 0
10-28 10:17:39.169  D/LOAD: OnCreateView LoadingObject: A  
10-28 10:17:39.870  D/POSITION: OnPageSelected CurrentItem: 1
10-28 10:17:40.070  D/PAGEVIEW: OnCreateView Position: 0
10-28 10:17:40.070  D/LOAD: OnCreateView LoadingObject: A
```

For this example in the list I only inserted 4 items (A, B, C, D) but item A is shown 2 times and D is never shown and it display the last fragment created and not the one it should display.

Any advice?

**EDIT:** Lupetto class code:

```
package gestionalebranco.walker93.com.gestionalebranco;

import com.orm.SugarRecord;

/**
 * Created by Workstation 2 on 26/09/2016.
 */

public class Lupetto extends SugarRecord{

    public String Nome;
    public String Cognome;
    public Sestiglie Sestiglia;
    public Pista Pista;
    public String Specialità;
    public boolean CdA;
    public Anagrafica Anagrafica;
    public String Prove;
    public static String Assenze;

    public Lupetto(){
    }

    public Lupetto(String nome, String cognome, Sestiglie sestiglia, Pista pista,
                   String specialità, boolean cda, Anagrafica anagrafica, String prove, String assenze) {

        this.Nome = nome;
        this.Cognome = cognome;
        this.Sestiglia = sestiglia;
        this.Pista = pista;
        this.Specialità = specialità;
        this.CdA = cda;
        this.Anagrafica = anagrafica;
        this.Prove = prove;
        this.Assenze = assenze;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the `Lupetto ` class.

Comment: @IulianPopescu Edited with the code you requested, even if I don't think will help.